# Can't open vs2003 project in vs2013

Tags: web-applications, visual-studio-2013, csproj, visual-studio-2003

I have couple of VS2003 web applications projects and can't open them in VS2013. Every time I get the following:

[image]

What modification should I make in .csproj file to be able open project in VS2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before, I recommend creating a new project with the correct .net framework, guessing .net 2.0, and then copy the files from the old project into the new project.

Comment: yes, I know I can create new project and then manually add files to it, I just tried to avoid it. I can also add web site in solution instead project, but unfortunately Microsoft removed option convert Web Site to Web Application from VS 2013.

Comment: Yeah, they want everyone to move to projects, instead of web sites. At my current job, we have to work with a LOT of old projects, they never open or convert 100% correctly. For me, manual import is the only solution that it headache free.

That been said, VS shouldn't be crashing when opening.

Comment: no, if they wanted to move everybody to projects, they should leave this option for convert to project. So actually I ended up removing projects from solution and adding them back as web sites.

Comment: probably you're right, it's better to create new project, not work with web sites.